# set -e and short tests

Tags: bash, shell, ksh, zsh

When I was new to shell scripting, I used a lot of short tests instead of `if` statements, like `false && true`.

Then later I learned using `set -e`, and found my scripts were dying for some reason, and they would work if I replaced the short tests with full `if` statements. Now, the time has gone, and I still use full `if` statements only.

The most interesting is that if I open an interactive shell and do the following:

```
set -e
false && true
echo $?
```

**it returns 1 but the shell doesn't die!**

I see that I have been wasting too many lines of code. Anyone could explain to me how can I use `set -e` with short tests safely, eg. without the script dying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding my problem of the script unexpectedly dying, it is due to running those short tests in a subshell, or from a function, and said function returns a value different than zero:

Original example:

```
$ set -e
$ false && true
$ echo $?
1
```

Using a subshell or function:

```
$ set -e
$ (false && true)
<script died>

$ set -e
$ variable=$(false && true)
<script died>

$ set -e
$ foo()(false && true)
$ foo
<script died>

$ set -e
$ foo(){ false && true; }
$ foo
<script died>
```

Possible solutions:

```
$ set -e
$ (false && true ||:)
$ (false && true) ||:
$ (if false; then true; fi)
```

Answer (score 43):

The [Single UNIX Specification](http://www.unix.org/single_unix_specification) describes the effect of `set -e` as:

> When this option is on, if a simple command fails for any of the reasons listed in Consequences of Shell Errors or returns an exit status value >0, and is not part of the compound list following a while, until, or if keyword, and is not a part of an AND or OR list, and is not a pipeline preceded by the ! reserved word, then the shell shall immediately exit.

As you see, a failing command in an AND list will not make the shell exit.

**Using `set -e`**

Starting shell scripts with `set -e` is considered a best practice, since it is usually safer to abort the script if some error occurs. If a command may fail harmlessly, I usually append `|| true` to it.

Here is a simple example:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

# [...]
# remove old backup files; do not fail if none exist
rm *~ *.bak || true
```

Comment: For the sake of the example, let's ignore the existence of `rm -f`.

Comment: Thank you! I just wonder why my early scripts would fail silently, unless I used full if statements... There must be some reason!

Comment: Could you provide an example of a script which fails silently unless you use full `if` statements?

Comment: I stopped using short tests a log time ago. What I can do is start reusing it and, if I find the issue again, post it here.

Comment: Are you still alive :) So many years later I found an example: subshells die silently on a `( false && true )`

Comment: Are you sure the subshell is dying silently and not simply returning the exit status of `( false && true )`, that is, `1`?

Comment: I said wrong, the subshell doesn't, but the shell dies due to the subshell returning `1`. In this case it is safer to use a `if` or `||:`

Comment: I believe this is expected: `false && true` is an AND list, and doesn't make the shell die, whereas `( false && true )` is seen by the (outer) shell as a single command. The parentheses _do_ make a difference.

Answer (score 5):

You need to end each command which may fail with `||` and a command or command list evaluating to 0. Using `||` will trigger your command if the expression before operator does not evaluate to 0. Your command needs to evaluate to 0 to not kill the shell.

Example:

```
set -e
false || true # silently ignore error

false || echo "Command failed, but exit status of echo is 0. Continuing..."

false || {                                                                      
  echo "Command failed. Continuing..."                                          
  # do something else                                                           
  false && true # all commands in the list need to be true                      
}
```

`false && true` does not cause an exit because ending expression is evaluated and evaluates to 0. From the bash man page for `set -e`:

> Exit  immediately  if  a pipeline (which may consist of a single
>   simple command), a subshell command enclosed in parentheses, or one of
>   the commands executed as part of a command list enclosed by braces
>   (see SHELL GRAMMAR above) exits with a non-zero status. **The shell
>   does not exit if the command that fails is** part of the command list
>   immediately following a while or until keyword, **part of the test
>   following the if** or elif reserved words, **part of any command executed
>   in a && or || list except the command following the final && or ||**,
>   any command in a pipeline but the last, or if the command's return
>   value is being inverted with !. A trap on ERR, if set, is executed
>   before the shell exits. This option applies to the shell environment
>   and each subshell environment separately (see COMMAND EXECUTION
>   ENVIRONMENT above), and may cause subshells to exit before executing
>   all the commands in the subshell.

Only last command if executed in `||`/`&&` chain can trigger exit.

The following expression will fail from the reason above.

```
true && false
```

but the following will not:

```
if true && false                                                                
then                                                                            
  true                                                                          
fi
```

because of `true && false` is part of test following `if`.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour of `set -e` is unintuitive in all but the simplest cases and has changed several times over the years. Therefore I do not recommend using it except in really simple scripts (plain sequences of commands).

Note that commands in a Makefile are usually executed with `set -e` in effect, so it is still often needed to understand something about how it works.

The `&&` and `||` operators allow a similar effect with relatively little clutter, but make it explicit. In particular, a `&&` might be placed at the end of a line much like a `;'.

Comment: I actually use `set -e` in scripts with thousands and thousands of lines of code. The best practice is in my opinion, use it in the development stages together with `set -x`, and then remove it if you are afraid it might fail after the release. Though I don't remove it even after the release, but only add `|| true` on a few lines I know may fail without issues.